# JSchException: timeout in waiting for rekeying process

Tags: jsch

A message is displayed indicating that the process of waiting for the key to be updated times out when JSCH is used for SSH connection
Here is my configuration:

```
Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        //get the JSCH session
        Session session = connectInfo.getJSch().getSession(serverConfig.getUsername(), serverConfig.getHost(), serverConfig.getPort());
        session.setConfig(config);
        //set password
        session.setPassword(serverConfig.getPassword());
        // Send null packet each 100s
        session.setServerAliveInterval(100);
        // Send 9999 max null packet
        session.setServerAliveCountMax(9999);
        // No connection timeout
        session.connect(0);

        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        channel.setCommand(command);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        channel.setErrStream(System.err);
        
        channel.connect();

        InputStream inputStream = channel.getInputStream();

        StringBuilder resultLines = new StringBuilder();
```

[image: 1]

Here's the actual log@Martin Prikryl

Comment: JSch log file? Complete exception details? Anything!

Comment: I added a picture of the specific journal

Answer (score 0):

I found the right answer！Error caused by my Linux server time inaccuracy,Synchronizing the exact time can solve this problem.